# Is it possible to conditionally load libraries in Lua?

Tags: unit-testing, lua

I'm making a script for [mpv](https://mpv.io/), and in it I load the `mpv` library like this:

```
-- script.lua

local mp = require('mp')
```

I'm using the `busted` unit test framework to write tests for this, and they're contained in a separate file, like this:

```
-- script-tests.lua

describe('my script unit tests', function()
    local script = require('script')

    it('...', function()
        assert.is_true(true)
    end)
end)
```

The problem occurs when I run the unit tests, I get this:

`./script.lua:1: module 'mp' not found:No LuaRocks module found for mp`

I understand `mp` is available when my script is run within `mpv`, but not when I run my unit tests. Is there any way to stop this `require` when running the unit tests? or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

## Solution

In the end I created a stub `mp` (trying to use a global flag like Adam suggested, but it wouldn't work). Here it is:

```
-- script.lua

local plugin = {}
local mpv_loaded, mp = pcall(require, 'mp')

plugin.mp = mp

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Stub MPV library for unit tests
if not mpv_loaded then
    plugin.mp = {}

    function plugin.mp.osd_message(message)
        plugin.mp.message = message
    end

    function plugin.mp.log(level, message)
        -- stub
    end

    function plugin.mp.add_forced_key_binding(...)
        -- stub
    end

    function plugin.mp.remove_key_binding(...)
        -- stub
    end
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Display message on screen.
function plugin:show_message(message)
    self.mp.osd_message(message)
end

return plugin
```

```
-- script-tests.lua

describe('my script unit tests', function()
    local plugin = require('script')

    it('...', function()
        message = 'It is better to play than do nothing.'
        plugin:show_message(message)

        assert.is_same(plugin.mp.message, message)
    end)

end)
```

Comment: Wouldn't your script not work if mpv couldn't be loaded? how can you test without it? You should probably implement a stub for the mpv lib that uses test data. If it doesn't and all you really care about is a conditional require, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you care about is a conditional require, meaning something to catch the require error:

```
local mpv_loaded, mp = pcall(function() return require 'mp' end)

if not mpv_loaded then
    -- handle the bad require, in this case 'mp' holds the error message
else
    -- 'mp' contains the lib as it normally would
end
```

Comment: You can write simply `pcall(require, 'mp')`.

Comment: This is perfect in my case, I only call a few functions from the `mp` library. Wrapping these calls in a conditional with `mpv_loaded` fixes everything, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could set a global variable in your unit tests and conditionally require the `mp` module.

For example, in your unit test, set a `_UNITTEST` variable:

```
-- script-tests.lua
_UNITTEST = true

describe('my script unit tests', function()
    local script = require('script')

    it('...', function()
        assert.is_true(true)
    end)
end)
```

Then, in your script:

```
-- script.lua
local mp = not _UNITTEST and require('mp')
```

A similar technique is used in the [Busted documentation](http://olivinelabs.com/busted/#private) to expose local values for testing. If you need to test functions that depend on the `mp` module, then you may want to look into providing a [stub](http://olivinelabs.com/busted/#spies-mocks-stubs) implementation.

Comment: I didn't think of this, thank you. I've accepted @ktb's answer because it better suits my particular case - as in, I only call a few functions from the mpv library and these can easily be wrapped in a conditional that checks `mpv_loaded`.

Comment: @MattDeacalionStevens Glad you found it useful. Just wanted to note that the expression `not _UNITTEST and require('mp')` is `false` when not loaded, so it the value of `mp` may also be used in a conditional. It also has the benefit of not hiding actual errors when requiring outside of the unit test.

Comment: I tried using a global, following the docs and your example. I kept getting the same error of no `mp` available. I've updated my question with what I went with in the end. Thanks again.